# What's the best configuration for Robots Meta plugin?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I need to know the best configuration for Robots Meta. That is a [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/robots-meta/) for seo.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to add more information: We don't know what the plug-in does, and what you need it to do. Please provide at least a link to the plug-in you're using

Comment: I thought it's a famous plugin and everyone has a wordpress blog know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Platinum SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/platinum-seo-pack/) it's the best plugin for seo for wordpress

Answer (score 2):

`index, follow` is probably the setting that makes the most sense if you want as many of your pages indexed as possible. Also, you probably want to prevent indexing of administration pages. That said, you will probably have to read the documentation of the plugin in order to choose the settings that suits your web site best.

Comment: I know index, follow :) but I'm puzzled in 3 things; I have Tag & Category & archives, any of them better to index as you know I want to avoid the duplicate content.
Thanks Klaus for your answer